# How to get a function from a edit box in matlab

Tags: matlab, function, user-interface

I have created a GUI in matlab with a edit box and the user should enter a function so the program may evaluate some values.

However how do I retrieve the function in the textbox and how do I make the proper validations for example if the user enters "sin(coserewrwfc(x))"

My code is:

```
f = get(handles.funcion,'String'); 
f =inline(f)
f(0)
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way of going about it. Basically it's the same as your code, but in a `try`/`catch` block so that if there is an error trying to do `f(0)`, the code will keep running. It will enter the `catch` statement, where you can manage the error, maybe by displaying a message box asking for the function to be entered again.

```
try
    f = inline(get(handles.funcion,'String'));
    f(0); %// try something that would fail if the function is defined incorrectly
catch
    disp('There was a problem, please try again')
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but its not working, i just tried your code and write in the edit box 2x+1, the answer should be 1 but is showing There was a problem, please try again. I think the problem is in the way I am handling the text as function. Please keep helping me dude

Comment: That's because `2x+1` is invalid syntax, it should be `2*x+1`.